# Custom build option for install python packages from remote repository

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, pybind11

I have a python project, which uses another python package built by me.
The package is originally implemented with C++ and made python bindings with pybind. When I try to install package with `pip` (actually with `pipenv`), the following line is added to `Pipfile` for installation:

```
[packages]
...
mypackage = {editable = true, ref = "main", git = "ssh://git@gitlab.com/myaccount/mypackage.git"}
```

There's `setup.py` file in the `mypackage` project and there's a cmake build code in that file. For now, it perfectly works. However, here's an issue: when I build the package `mypackage`, I want to give a custom option for that, but I can't find the way to give such option *when I install packages (include `mypackage`) in the project*.
For now, the option is somehow hard-coded, and I can't change the option during installation with pipenv (`pipenv install --dev`).
I think I need to modify the `setup.py` in `mypackage` and add suitable option to the `Pipfile` as follows:

```
mypackage = {editable = true, ref = "main", git = "ssh://git@gitlab.com/myaccount/mypackage.git", custom_build_option = "option1"}
```

but I cannot figure out how to make this really works. Thanks in advance.